# get data from angular firebase firestore database

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have Angular 6, `"@angular/fire": "^5.1.1", "firebase": "^5.6.0"`, and I'm trying of fetch data of my database but it doesn't work.

i have a function called `getCadenaFecha()`, here i have a logic that take any number of days and subtract them from the current date, then it store in `cadena` to make a query and fetch data from firestore, when i return the variable `ultimoDia`, it doesn't fetch the data

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tempFirebaseRepo } from './../Repository/tempFirebase'
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {Dispositivo} from './../models/Dispositivo';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class query {
    dispositivoRef:AngularFirestoreCollection<Dispositivo>;
    dispositivoRefUno:AngularFirestoreCollection<Dispositivo>;
    dispositivoRefDos:AngularFirestoreCollection<Dispositivo>;
    dispositivoRefTres:AngularFirestoreCollection<Dispositivo>;
    ultimaSemana: Observable<Dispositivo[]>;
    ultimoDia: Observable<Dispositivo[]>;

    constructor(private afs:AngularFirestore, private _tempFirebaseRepo:tempFirebaseRepo){}

    getDia(){

        let cadena=this._tempFirebaseRepo.getCadenaFecha(20)

        //aca esta la query de Firestore
        this.dispositivoRef = this.afs.collection('Dispositivo', ref =>{
            return ref.where('Dispositivo', '>', Number(cadena))
        })
        debugger;
        this.ultimoDia = this.dispositivoRef.valueChanges(); 

        return this.ultimoDia;

    }
}
```

....and this is my app.module:

```
          import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
      import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
      import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
      import {ChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts';
      import {routing, appRoutingProviders} from './app.routing';
      import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
      import {AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
      import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
      import { tempFirebaseRepo } from './Repository/tempFirebase';

      //componentes
      import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
      import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
      import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
      import { SettingsComponent } from './components/settings/settings.component';
      import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';
      import { DataComponent } from './components/menu/data/data.component';
      import { InformeMesComponent } from './components/menu/informe/informe-mes/informe-mes.component';


      @NgModule({
        declarations: [
          AppComponent,
          HeaderComponent,
          FooterComponent,
          SettingsComponent,
          MenuComponent,
          DataComponent,
          InformeMesComponent,

        ],
        imports: [
          HttpClientModule,
          BrowserModule,
          ChartsModule,
          routing,
          AngularFirestoreModule,
          AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        ],
        providers: [
          appRoutingProviders,
          tempFirebaseRepo
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
      })
      export class AppModule { }
```

...this is my component, here is the subscribe:

```
        import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
    import {TemperaturaService} from '../../../services/Temperatura/Temperatura.service';
    //import {tempFirebaseService} from '../../../services/tempFirebase/temp-firebase.service';
    import {Global} from '../../../services/Temperatura/global';
    import {tempFirebaseRepo} from '../../../Repository/tempFirebase'
    import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import {query} from '../../../Repository/query'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-data',
      templateUrl: './data.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./data.component.css'],
      providers: [TemperaturaService, /*tempFirebaseService*/ ]
    })
    export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
      public data:any[];
      public url: string;
      public Chart = [];
      public dia=[];
      public mes=[];
      public year=[];
      public hora=[];
      public minuto=[];
      public medicion=[];
      public fecha=[];
      public Fecha=[];
      public lineChartData:Array<any>=[{data: [], label: ''}];
      public lineChartLabels:Array<any>=this.Fecha;
      public currentDate:number;



      constructor(
        //private _tempFirebaseService: tempFirebaseService,
        private _tempFirebaseRepo:tempFirebaseRepo,
        private _query: query
        ) { 
          this.url = Global.url;    
        }


          ngOnInit() {
            this.getDia();
          }

          //Obtener con api rest
          getDia(){
            this._query.getDia().subscribe(
              response => { 

                this.lineChartData=this._tempFirebaseRepo
                    .OrdenarResponse(response, 
                                      this.fecha, 
                                      this.medicion, 
                                      this.dia, 
                                      this.mes, 
                                      this.year, 
                                      this.hora,
                                      this.minuto, 
                                      this.Fecha,
                                      this.lineChartData
                    );

                debugger;
              },
              error =>{
                console.log(<any>error);
              }
            );
          }
          /*getSemana(){

              this._tempFirebaseService.getUltimaSemana().subscribe(
                  response => { 

                    this.lineChartData=this._tempFirebaseRepo
                        .OrdenarResponse(response, 
                                          this.fecha, 
                                          this.medicion, 
                                          this.dia, 
                                          this.mes, 
                                          this.year, 
                                          this.hora,
                                          this.minuto, 
                                          this.Fecha,
                                          this.lineChartData
                        );

                    debugger;
                  },
                  error =>{
                    console.log(<any>error);
                  }
              );

          }*/
          /* getMes(){
            this._tempFirebaseService.getUltimoMes().subscribe(
              response => { 

                this.lineChartData=this._tempFirebaseRepo
                    .OrdenarResponse(response, 
                                      this.fecha, 
                                      this.medicion, 
                                      this.dia, 
                                      this.mes, 
                                      this.year, 
                                      this.hora,
                                      this.minuto, 
                                      this.Fecha,
                                      this.lineChartData
                    );

                debugger;
              },
              error =>{
                console.log(<any>error);
              }
          );
          }*/

          // lineChart
        public lineChartOptions:any = {
            responsive: true
          };

          public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
            { // grey
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
              pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
              pointBorderColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
            },
            { // dark grey
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
              pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
              pointBorderColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
            },
            { // grey
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
              pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
              pointBorderColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
            }
          ];
          public lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
          public lineChartType:string = 'line';

          // events
          public chartClicked(e:any):void {
            console.log(e);
          }

          public chartHovered(e:any):void {
            console.log(e);
          }
    }
```

....the response always is empty

[image]

....this is my database:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very specific. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53637041/edit) to let us know what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it? [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful

Comment: ok, i have a function called getCadenaFecha(), here i have a logic that take any number of days and subtract them from the current date, then it store in "cadena" to make a query and fetch data from firestore, when i return the variable "ultimoDia", it doesn't fetch the data.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up `ultimoDia` as an observable, and then never subscribing to it. Read up on [observables and subscriptions](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3), and you'll understand why your code isn't working. Basically, you are saying "*This is the data I will want to listen to*" but then you're never actually beginning to listen.

Your mistake is a common one - the AngularFire2 docs are horrible for people unfamiliar with observables/subscriptions. Include a `.subscribe()` to see your data, something like:

```
return this.dispositivoRef.valueChanges().subscribe(queriedItems => {
    console.log(queriedItems);
    return queriedItems;
});
```

**Untested code*

Comment: hi man, i forgot paste the code when i have the subscribe, i have the subscribe on a component called "datacomponent.ts", i'm gonna update the post with this file

Comment: also i posted an image debugging in the browser console, the response always is empty

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.... okay, well that looks right. I don't see any errors in your console in the screenshot - all that combined makes me suspect that the DB call is working, just that the DB doesn't send anything back for that query.... meaning that your query is incorrect. So....  my next step would be checking if we can get ANYTHING back from the database. Try eliminating the filter criteria, just having `this.dispositivoRef = this.afs.collection('Dispositivo');`... can you include a screenshot of your database structure too please?

Comment: i commented this lines:                                                              
        this.dispositivoRef = this.afs.collection('Dispositivo'/*, ref =>{
            return ref.where('Dispositivo', '>', Number(cadena))
        }*/)

Comment: but how can i make this query, one week ago it worked, is anything bad in this qery?

Comment: Wew! Narrowed it down :) Nothing looks obviously off, but I'd need to see your database structure to be able to help further.

Comment: the property "timestamp" and "medicion" are type number

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and double check that the value of `cadena` in the line `let cadena=this._tempFirebaseRepo.getCadenaFecha(20)` is actually being set? Making sure there's actually a number to compare against...

Comment: Also, your query doesn't make any sense given your database structure. You are trying to find results where the entire data node is greater than a value? Doesn't work that way, you need to compare a specific property of the node... in your case, the medicion, sensor, timestamp, etc... so like: `ref.where('sensor', '>', 5)`

Comment: "cadena" is a number that represent year, month, day, hour and minute, this number every day is biggest

Comment: at the function "getCadenaFecha(here, number to days back)", i have a logic that return this number

Comment: Okay. Well regardless of your logic for `cadena`, your `where` clause is the big problem here. Check out the [docs on querying collections in AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md), good luck :)